# If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ is a prime, then $\frac{p-1}{2}! \equiv \pm1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

> If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ is a prime, then $\frac{p-1}{2}! \equiv \pm1 \pmod p$.

I don't know how to prove this statement.

$p=4m+3$, so $(2m+1)! \equiv \pm1\pmod p$

This is all I did.

Comment: Do you know Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Shall I interpret that as "No, I'm new to the topic, I haven't yet heard of it"?

Comment: Related: [Why does $(\frac{p-1}{2}!)^2 = (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ mod $p$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131175); probably there are more similar duplicates

Comment: $p\text{ is prime}\iff (p-1)!+1\equiv0\pmod{p}$

Comment: And you should most definitely change $(p-1/2)!$ to $((p-1)/2)!$

Comment: @grgarside: That's a very bad edit!!! It is pretty obvious that OP did not mean $(p-\frac12)!$

Comment: @barak It's not obvious at all—I went purely off the raw. I've edited it to $\frac{p-1}2$.

Comment: @barakmanos It makes sense to interpret $\frac{1}{2}$ as the multiplicative inverse of $2$ modulo $p$. And then, lo and behold, $$p - \frac{1}{2} = p - \frac{p+1}{2} = \frac{p-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\left( \frac{p-1}{2}! \right)^2 = \prod \limits_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}n·\prod \limits_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}n=\prod \limits_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}n·\prod \limits_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-n \equiv\prod \limits_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}n·\prod \limits_{n=\frac{p+1}{2}}^{p-1}n=(p-1)! \equiv 1$

You can change $n$ for $-n$ because there is an even number of factors from $1$ to $\frac{n-1}{2}$

Therefore, $ \frac{p-1}{2}!$ is congruent to either $1$ or $-1$

Answer (score 1):

> **Wilson's theorem**
>
> $$(p-1)!\equiv_p -1$$
>
> *Proof*: Every element $x\in\Bbb Z_p^\times$ has a unique inverse $y\in\Bbb Z_p^\times$ such that $xy\equiv_p 1$, except $-1,1$ since they are their own inverses, i.e., they satisfy $x^2\equiv_p 1$.
>
> This inverse is unique, since if both $y,y'$ were inverses of $x$, then $$xy\equiv_p xy'\equiv_p 1\Rightarrow y\equiv_p y'$$ Now in the product $(p-1)!$ every element is multiplied with it's corresponding inverse, except $-1$ and $1$, which means $$(p-1)!\equiv_p 1\cdot 1\cdot\ldots\cdot 1\cdot (-1)\equiv_p -1$$

$(p-1)!\equiv_p 1\cdot (-1)\cdot 2\cdot (-2)\cdot \ldots\cdot \frac{p-1}{2}\cdot (-\frac{p-1}{2})\equiv_p (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left (\frac{p-1}{2}\right )!^2$

By Wilson's theorem $-1\equiv_p(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left (\frac{p-1}{2}\right )!^2$

Using that $p\equiv_4 3$ we get $$\left (\frac{p-1}{2}\right )!\equiv_p \pm1$$

Comment: Could you explain me the last part? I don’t see how using $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ you obtain that result. Thank you

Comment: @OctavioBerlanga If $p\equiv_4 3$ then $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1$, thus you get $1\equiv_p \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2$. Are you satisfied?

Comment: I am satisfied, thank you.