# Prove that if $p \equiv 1 \mod4$, then $[((p-1)/2)!]^2 \equiv (p-1)! \mod p$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The original problem is to prove that if p $\equiv 1 \mod{4}$, then $[((p-1)/2)!]^2 \equiv -1 \mod{p}$, and the problem in the title is given as a hint.

Comment: Use the fact that $-a \equiv p - a \pmod{p}$ many times, and leverage Wilson's theorem.

Comment: See also, from some brief searching, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1485760. It's for the $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ case, but it's a minor detail toward the end only.