# A problem on modular arithmetic.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factorial

How is $\left(\frac {p-1}{2}\right)! ^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$. I was using this result for a proof ($x^2$ = -1 (mod p) ) and was stuck on this part. NOTE, this result is only when p is a prime of form 4k+1.

note: please don't delete my question without atleast informing me of the reason.

Comment: Is $ p $ prime ?. If yes, think of Wilson's theorem.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yes p is a prime, i realize that we need to apply wilson's theorem but that states p | (p-1)! + 1 so i am not sure how to apply that to this problem.

Comment: You know you can enclose entire expressions in dollar signs, rather than just one symbol at a time? For instance, instead of `($\frac {p-1}{2}$)! $^2$ $\equiv$ -1 (mod p)`, try `$(\frac {p-1}{2})! ^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$` to get $(\frac {p-1}{2})! ^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$. Looks better.

Comment: @Arthur , i am sorry, i did not know that. I will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: This can't be true for all primes $p$, since $-1$ is not always a square $\bmod{p}$. What you want to show is that, if $p \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^{2} = (p-1)!$

Comment: Also, this is already answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Comment: @MorganRodgers yes exactly. Thank you! i am sorry for the mistake

Comment: $-1\equiv(p-1)!\equiv 1\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{p-1}{2}\frac{p+1}{2}\cdot\ldots\cdot(p-1)\equiv\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2\cdot(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2$ , @MorganRodgers this was what i am having trouble with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does $(\frac{p-1}{2}!)^2 = (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ mod $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131175/why-does-fracp-122-1-fracp12-mod-p). With $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, this gives a RHS of $-1$ while for $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, it gives a RHS of $1$.

Comment: @Aditya_math It really is just a matter of writing out all of the terms. Try it for $p=5$ and for $p=13$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thank you so much, this was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your claim seems false:

Take $ p=7$.

$$(\frac{p-1}{2})!=3!=6$$

$$6^2=36\equiv 1 \mod 7$$

Comment: this was used in constructive proving of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914613/x2-equiv-1-mod-p , so could you please explain then how we prove this

Comment: i am sorry, i meant for primes of form 4k + 1

Comment: @Aditya_math $$7=4.1+3$$

Comment: oh no, i am really sorry. i mean 4k+1

Comment: ie, this claim is possible only for p = 4k+1